# boost::filesystem recursively getting size of each file

Tags: c++, file, boost, filesystems, boost-filesystem

Why does this code throw an error when the argument is a directory?

Using `boost::recursive_directory_iterator` and using `std::cout` statements, I can see that it never prints a directory; only files. But, when I try to call `boost::filesystem::file_size()`, an error is thrown basically saying I'm trying to get the file size of a directory.

Error (argument was **"/home"**):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::file_size: Operation not permitted: "/home/lost+found"
Aborted
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) return -1;

    const fs::path file{argv[1]};

    if (!fs::exists(file)) return -1;

    if (fs::is_regular_file(file))
        std::cout << file << "   [ " << fs::file_size(file) << " ]\n";

    else if (fs::is_directory(file))
        for (const fs::directory_entry& f : fs::recursive_directory_iterator{file})
            std::cout << f.path().filename() << "   [ " << fs::file_size(f.path()) << " ]\n";
}
```

Compiled with: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++14 -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -O2 -Os -s test3.cpp -o test3`

Comment: *"Using boost::recursive_directory_iterator and using std::cout statements, I can see that it never prints a directory; only files."* -- Are you sure about that? It should print directories too. It does when I use it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I guess it just throws an exception on the first directory met and program terminates. So OP doesn't see any directories.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: Could be. I assumed that he meant he tried it with only printing the filename, and not trying to get the file size. Hence the *"But, when I try to call boost::filesystem::file_size() ..."*.

Comment: When I tested `boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`, the program printed out a large amount of text. I missed that it prints out directories as well as files. Thanks @BenjaminLindley.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'   what():
> boost::filesystem::file_size: Operation not permitted:
> **"/home/lost+found"** Aborted

It means that it can't get the size of */home/lost+found*. Normally, *lost+found* is a folder and [`file_size` only get the size of regular files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#file_size).

I understand that the loop does not show the name of this folder. It may be because the compiler is evaluating `fs::file_size(f.path())` and throwing the exception before calling `operator<<` for the file name so it does not get printed.

I think the loop should be modified to check for a regular file before asking for the size:

```
for (const fs::directory_entry& f : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(folder)) {
  if (fs::is_regular_file(f.path())) {
    std::cout << f.path().filename() << "   [ " << fs::file_size(f.path()) << " ]\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to actually recursively get the size:

```
size_t du(fs::path p) {
    return fs::is_regular_file(p)
       ? file_size(p)
       : boost::accumulate(fs::directory_iterator{p}, 0ull, [](auto a, auto p){return a+du(p);});
}
```

This will work for directories by summing (`accumulate`) the files in all underlying directories.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eab7ec85fa58f503)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
size_t du(fs::path p) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << p << ")\n";
    return fs::is_regular_file(p)
       ? file_size(p)
       : boost::accumulate(fs::directory_iterator{p}, 0ull, [](auto a, auto p){return a+du(p);});
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) return -1;

    std::cout << "Size is " << du(argv[1]) << "\n";
}
```

With the debug `std::cout` enabled:

```
Size is du(".")
du("./main.cpp")
du("./a.out")
22435
```

Comment: Won't this get the size of files nested in directories multiple times? `recursive_directory_iterator` already handles the recursion of going down into nested directories, but then you're handling it again by calling `du(p)` recursively.

Comment: Sheepish grin. @BenjaminLindley Fixed! I guess you could use `recursive_`* and just feed it into `accumulate